# After upgrading to PHP8.2 on GAE, upload no longer work to Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, php-8.2

My web app has been working fine for many years on PHP7 on Google App Engine and Cloud Storage. This week I'm updating to PHP8 and have fixed the usual issues with stricter types, etc.  The only issue left is that my file upload function does not work with PHP8.

My code works locally with Apache/PHP8 and works if I revert back to a PHP7 version on GAE.  I don't see any errors (or I don't know how to find them) in the App Engine logs. PHP does not stop executing, but just doesn't save the uploads to Cloud Storage.  Here is my code:

```
session_start();

// Use the composer autoloader to load dependencies.
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
try {
    $storage = new StorageClient();
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}


// Cloud Storage Settings
$_SESSION['project_id'] = "xxapp";
$_SESSION['bucket_name'] = "xxapp.appspot.com";
$_SESSION['devStorage'] = "https://storage.googleapis.com/xxapp.appspot.com/uploads/";

$success = upload_to_GCP_Storage($storage,
    $_FILES["cert_".$_POST['updateVERI_ID']]["name"],
    $_FILES["cert_".$_POST['updateVERI_ID']]["tmp_name"],
    ''
);


function upload_to_GCP_Storage($storage, $objectName, $source, $option) {

    $type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($objectName,"."),1));
    if($type == 'jpeg') $type = 'jpg';

    try {
        $dir = sys_get_temp_dir();

        switch(strtolower($type)) {
            case 'jpg': break;
            case 'png': break;
            case 'pdf': break;               
            case 'doc': break;  
            case 'docx': break;  
            case 'xls': break;  
            case 'xlsx': break;  
            default : return "Unsupported file type!";
        }
        $newFileName = md5(time().$objectName).".".$type;

        // Move uploaded file to temporary directory
        if (!move_uploaded_file($source, dir.'/'.$newFileName)) {
            handleError("Failed to move uploaded file");
        }

        $bucket = $storage->bucket($_SESSION["bucket_name"]);

        $f = fopen($dir.'/'.$newFileName, 'r');
            $object = $bucket->upload($f, [
                'name' => 'uploads/'.$newFileName
            ]);
        $object->update(['acl' => []], ['predefinedAcl' => 'PUBLICREAD']); // makes public readable
            
        fclose($f); // this removes the tmp file

        return $newFileName;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        handleError($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Has something changed with how my code should be since PHP7? Is the composer storage library compatible with PHP8? How do I check?  Any other suggestions are welcome ... time is running out since PHP7 won't be supported on GAE after Jan 31st.

Thanks,
-Mark

Comment: Are you using the same `major.minor` version locally and in App Engine? There have been breaking changes between 8.0 -> 8.1 -> 8.2 including PHP extensions. More details are required. For example, what composer storage library are you using? Did you check if it is supported by the PHP version? I recommend adding logs to your program so that you can see what is executing and the variable values. Edit your question and add `composer.json`.

Comment: @john
Local:  PHP Version 8.2.12
GAE:    PHP Version 8.2.14
Composer JSON:
`
{
    "require": {
        "auth0/auth0-php": "^7.5",
        "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "^2.5",
        "google/cloud-storage": "^1.23",
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "^3.2",
        "php-http/message": "^1.11",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
        "php-http/discovery": "^1.13",
        "php-http/curl-client": "^2.2",
        "nyholm/psr7": "^1.4",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0",
        "maennchen/zipstream-php": "^2.1"
    }
}
`

Comment: Always put new information in your question and not via comments. Some details are too hard.

Comment: You are using `google/cloud-storage` version 1.23. The current version is 1.37. Your version is from June 2021. PHP 8.2 was released in December 2022. 8.2.14 was released in December 2023. You are mixing old libraries with newer platforms.

Comment: Update all of the composer dependencies, then test again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @John Hanley for your suggestion to check composer dependencies.

After several days and adding in error logging, I also found a PHP8 change that broke part of my upload procedure.  fclose($f) will create a fatal error if $f no longer exists.